# Community - Preconfigured Pages

Tags: community

I have created some preconfigured community pages that have proven useful when making new community pages.  However, I am now unable to create new custom object pages.  Salesforce is looking into the issue.  They seem to be implying so far that the problem might be because I am using a custom template.  I am skeptical of this since I have been successfully using the custom template for 1.5 years without problem.  The only new thing I can think I have done is created these preconfigured community pages by using Salesforce's export a Community page template feature.  Does anyone know how to delete the preconfigured pages I created?  I want to see if this might fix the problem.

Comment: I found how to delete the preconfigured community pages - Setup/Lightning Community Pages.  I will now see if this fixes my problem of not being able to create new community object pages.

Comment: I still have the problem of not being able to create community object pages any more.  Thoughts?